# Represent elements in $H_{n-1}(M;\mathbb{Z})$ by a connected hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M^n$ be a closed orientable manifold. Then it is well-known that every class in $H_{n-1}(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is represented by a closed hypersurface. A proof can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21171/when-is-a-homology-class-represented-by-a-submanifold). However, it is also stated in that post that when the dimension $n>2$, we can take the hyersurface to be connected. I was wondering how to prove the connectedness.

Comment: You forgot to assume that $M$ is connected. As a hint: connect different components by pairwise disjoint tubes and show that this does not change the homology class.